# How to add a duplicate key into a dict as in PHP?

Tags: python-2.7, solr

I am trying to get python working with solr, however I am stuck at the process of adding multiple docs with one request. (A string gets split into words and adds them into multiple update commands)

I already tried adding the dictionary to lists however solr doesn't want to understand it that way which is really annoying.

---

Expected JSON:

```
{
    "add": {
        "doc": {
            "Text": "WORD_HERE",
            "ID": "ID_HERE"
        }
    },
    "add": {
        "doc": {
            "Text": "WORD_HERE",
            "ID": "ID_HERE"
        }
    },
    "commit": {}
}
```

---

Python:

```
for word in wordList:
    payload.update({"add": { "doc": { "Text": word, "ID": str(uuid.uuid4()) }}})
payload.update({"commit": {}})
f = open("outputjsontest.txt", "a")
f.write(json.dumps(payload))
```

---

Result JSON: (Which is logical)

```
{
    "add": {
        "doc": {
            "Text": "I",
            "ID": "e5324345-4ac0-4143-bbc7-73235331f5b3"
        }
    },
    "commit": {}
}
```

I know this isn't correct json however solr parses understands it. My question now is, is there any way to design the payload like shown above? I am not really good at python however a library I need is only available in python.

Comment: Are you only adding documents? In that case Solr [supports receiving a list of objects](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/uploading-data-with-index-handlers.html#UploadingDatawithIndexHandlers-AddingMultipleJSONDocuments), instead of objects under the "add" key.

Comment: Ah yes it seems that this works too, its so simple and yet I tried it that hard. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [Solr supports a list of objects](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/uploading-data-with-index-handlers.html#UploadingDatawithIndexHandlers-AddingMultipleJSONDocuments)! So my attempts were really useless hehe. Thanks to @MatsLindh for solving the issue!